# Problem Deploying to Artifactory with Checksum (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, artifactory, checksum

Okay,
Well, I'm trying to figure out how to do this.
I've ready the API and and yet this never works.

```cs
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    if (!path.EndsWith("/")) path = $"{path}/";
    string url = config.CreateRequest(client, null, $"{path}{file.Name}");
    string sha1 = JFrogLoader.GetSha1Hash(file);
    string sha256 = JFrogLoader.GetSha256Hash(file);
    string md5 = JFrogLoader.GetMD5Hash(file);
    using (Stream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        StreamContent content = new StreamContent(stream);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Deploy", "true");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Sha1", sha1);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Sha256", sha256);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum", md5);
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PutAsync(url, content);
        string response = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return message.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created;
    }
}
```

The thing is, if I don't use any of the `"X-Checksum-"` header items, the deploy works, but when you navigate to the page in Artifactory, it has the "Fix Checksum" button.  So I figured I should probably provide them.
My methods that generate the checksums use the "*CryptoServiceProvider" classes, and trim the final '=' from the computed hash string.  But every time I add in the checksum headers, I get a multi-part exception for "Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host".

I've tried using the `content.Headers` and `client.DefaultRequestHeaders`.
I've tried only providing the `SHa1`.
I've tried naming the `md5` `X-Checksum-Md5` (which is not in the api, but figured it was worth a shot).
Nothing works, and i get a connection closed by host.

Any ideas how I should resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, took a while but using a little trial and error, i found the problem was in the has algorithm I was using.

The Correct Solution to load this via C# with checksums is as follows:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    if (!path.EndsWith("/")) path = $"{path}/";
    string url = config.CreateRequest(client, null, $"{path}{file.Name}");
    string sha1 = JFrogLoader.GetSha1Hash(file);
    string sha256 = JFrogLoader.GetSha256Hash(file);
    string md5 = JFrogLoader.GetMD5Hash(file);
    using (Stream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        StreamContent content = new StreamContent(stream);
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Deploy", "true");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Sha1", sha1);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Sha256", sha256);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Checksum-Md5", md5);
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PutAsync(url, content);

        string response = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return message.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created;
    }
}

public static string GetSha1Hash(FileInfo file)
{
    using (var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return JFrogLoader.GetHash(file, sha1);
    }
}

public static string GetSha256Hash(FileInfo file)
{
    using (SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return JFrogLoader.GetHash(file, sha256);
    }
}

public static string GetMD5Hash(FileInfo file)
{
    using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        return JFrogLoader.GetHash(file, md5);
    }
}

private static string GetHash(FileInfo file, HashAlgorithm hasher)
{
    using (Stream stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    {
        byte[] hash = hasher.ComputeHash(stream);
        return BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", "").ToLower();
    }
}
```

The key was originally i was using a Convert.ToBase64String instead of the BitConverter to a straight hex string.  Tragically, Artifcatory was not clear in it's error message, and triggered an exception in the web request.

Thanks